# Displaying images associated with url's in a xamarin forms listview

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am building a mobile app with xamarin forms. I have a listview that will store description about a url. I want to be able to display the icons or images that are tied to the url without saving images in my database. When you text a url to someone, am image shows with the url. Any ideas how this can be done? I have been researching and no luck.

Comment: do you mean the favicon?  Or if not, a concrete example of what you're talking about would be helpful.

Comment: Yes a favicon is what I mean. That way I can just pull it and display it with the description of the url in the listview

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) on it?  What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: When you send a text message to a friend like www.yahoo.com. Once the text go through, you will see the Yahoo Icon. I want to be able store this Icon and text in my listview

Comment: I understand that.  Are you having problems understanding how to get the url for the icon?  Or how to display it in a ListView?

Comment: How to display the icon in a listview is what I don't know how to do.

Comment: I also have several urls stored in my database which I am pulling in a field. It is a property in a model

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps , specify a UriImage source for your image, set the uri property to the image url

```
               <Image 
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Aspect="AspectFit">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <UriImageSource Uri="{Binding EventImage}" 
                            CacheValidity="3" 
                            CachingEnabled="true"/>
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>
```

Comment: I am not storing an image. I want to be able to pull the image from the url

Comment: Will this code pull the image from the url and store it in a listview for me?

Comment: Yeah create a property in your view model and use that instead of EventImage

Comment: Make sure you set the value of that property to your image URL

Comment: @user2320476 yeah I'm using data binding , replace {Binding EventImage} with your url

Answer (score 1):

to display in Image in a ListView, use an ImageCell

```
<ImageCell ImageSource="{Binding FaviconUrl}" Text="{Binding Name}" />
```

You'll have to add a property to your model that will determine (or guess) the correct url for the site's favicon.

Comment: I do have all url's stored in my database which am pulling. I also have a field called description. I want to show the description and the favicon url in my listview

Comment: I'm suggesting you add a property to your model which will return the favicon url based on the url you already have in the db.

Comment: Can www.yahoo.com be the faviconUrl?

Comment: No.  You need to specify the direct link to the icon - https://www.yahoo.com/favicon.ico

Comment: That's what am trying to explain. I don't have the direct link to the icon. I have over a thousand urls in my database. I am not able to identify the favicons url.

Comment: I asked you above if you understood how to figure that out, and you said you just didn't understand how to display an image in a ListView.  The wikipedia article I linked to also clearly explains the different methods of find the icon url.  Basically it's either referenced in a page's meta data (which requires you to read the page first) or you can try to load it from the domains root: www.domain.tld/favicon.ico.  If you have a url in your db, building the url for /favicon.ico should be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the fav-icon using the [Google S2 converter](https://www.labnol.org/internet/get-favicon-image-of-websites-with-google/4404/).

**For e.g:**
https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=yahoo.com : [image: icon]

To get it to work with your image control, this should technically work:

```
<ImageCell Text="{Binding DomainUrl}">
  <ImageCell.ImageSource>
    <UriImageSource Uri="{Binding Path=DomainUrl, StringFormat='https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain={0}'}"
      CacheValidity="1"
      CachingEnabled="true"/>
  </ImageCell.ImageSource>           
</ImageCell>
```

Or,

```
<ViewCell>
  <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">
    <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
      <Image.Source>
        <UriImageSource Uri="{Binding Path=DomainUrl, StringFormat='https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain={0}'}"
          CacheValidity="1"
          CachingEnabled="true"/>
      </Image.Source>                       
    </Image>
    <Label Text="{Binding Path=DomainUrl}" /> 
  </StackLayout>            
</ViewCell>
```